# How can I get the parameters when POSTing from a form using Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having problems getting the POSTed data when using a form in Express.

My form is pretty straight forward:

```
<form action="/api/v1/items" method="post">
    <p>
        <span>Name:</span><br>
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Priority:</span><br>
        <input type="text" id="priority">
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Comment:</span><br>
        <input type="text" id="comment">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Item">
</form>
```

Here is the implementation of the endpoint on the server:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const data = {
        'name': req.body.name,
        'priority': parseInt(req.body.priority),
        'comment': req.body.comment
    };

    // do something with the data
});

module.exports = router;
```

The route should be registered correctly:

```
var app = express();
var items = require('./routes/items');

app.use('/api/v1/items', items);
```

The problem is that when the form is submitted, `req.body` has no parameters.

I created my app using the Express generator, so the `body-parser` middleware should be set up correctly:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

The strange thing is that if I use `curl` to POST the data, the parameters are sent correctly:

```
curl --data "name=Something&priority=1&comment=Whatever" http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/items
```

Since curl works, this tells me that something is wrong with my form, although I have no idea what could be wrong there.

What do I need to do in order to get the parameters POSTed from the form to be parsed correctly in Express?

Comment: Are you sure that bodyParser init goes before routes?

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk Yes - bodyParser is registered before the routes are registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs in your form should have `name`s rather than `id`s

```
<form action="/api/v1/items" method="post">
    <p>
        <span>Name:</span><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Priority:</span><br>
        <input type="text" name="priority">
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Comment:</span><br>
        <input type="text" name="comment">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Item">
</form>
```

You may find [specification on form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)  useful.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the help! :)